# Can't change screen orientation for the scene in cocos3d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos3d

I have a view controller in which I show some `cocos3d` content. In my appDelegate:

```
+(CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController *)panoramaHostController {
static CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController *panoramaHostController = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    panoramaHostController = CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController.sharedDirector;
    panoramaHostController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    panoramaHostController.viewShouldUseStencilBuffer = NO;     // Set to YES if using shadow volumes
    panoramaHostController.viewPixelSamples = 1;                    // Set to 4 for antialiasing multisampling
    panoramaHostController.animationInterval = (1.0f / 60.0f);
    panoramaHostController.displayStats = NO;
    [panoramaHostController enableRetinaDisplay: YES];
});
return panoramaHostController;
}
```

and in panoramaHostController I initialize the scene this way:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

//
if (!sceneInitialized) {
    sceneInitialized = YES;

    CC3Layer *axPanoramaLayer = [AxPanoramaLayer layer];
    axPanoramaLayer.contentSize =  [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    [CCDirector.sharedDirector runWithScene: [axPanoramaLayer asCCScene]];
}
else {
    [[AppDelegate panoramaHostController] resumeAnimation];
}

[self.view addSubview: CCDirector.sharedDirector.view];
...
}
```

but when I rotate the device - the content stays the same. What's wrong here?

Comment: As with any iOS app, make sure you also make the appropriate device orientation selections within your Xcode project settings. You can find these in the Deployment Info section on the General tab of your app Target.

Comment: @BillHollings thi settings set correctly in my project - should the CCDirector change its winSize according to the correct screen orientation?

Comment: When is your panoramaHostController created? Since it IS the CCDirector singleton, you must run that code before any other access to CCDirector.sharedDirector. Otherwise the CCDeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController will not become the CCDirector singleton. See the hello world template app for an example of invoking this right on app startup.